# Powershell not waiting before next line gets executed

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script that takes a screenshot after successfully pinging a server. This is the current state of my script:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path .\SOXEvidenceServersList.csv -Header 'VM', 'FQDN'

foreach($fqdn in $CSV) {
    ping $fqdn.VM -n 1 -a | Out-String
    [void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.windows.forms")
    [system.windows.forms.sendkeys]::sendwait('{PRTSC}')
    Get-Clipboard -Format Image | ForEach-Object -MemberName Save -ArgumentList "C:\Users\test\Documents\PowerShellScripts\$($fqdn.VM).png"
    Clear-Host
}
```

The problem is that my powershell script is not waiting before taking the screenshot, even after including the `| Out-String` or `| Out-Null` to the 4th line.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When using powershell, why not use the native test-connection cmdlet to test servers connection? You can also use `start-sleep 1` if you want to pause before continuing

Comment: Out-string and out-null doesnt make the script pause ... they only redirect the output.